# Windows service application config file is getting corrputed and filled with NULLs

Tags: c#, service, thread-safety, app-config, corruption

I have a windows service installed on 200+ machines. On a small number of machines, and it appears totally random, the config file gets corrupted and filled with NULLs. This appears to happen randomly. The config file size is the same as when installed however when it is opened in Notepad it looks empty. When opened in Notepad++ it is possible to see the NULLs.

The windows service hosts 2 processes. One reads from, and writes a value signifying it is active. The second process just reads from the file. These services are started using a CRON scheduler. Log4net reports nothing about the failure. The service just stops, reporting that the config file cannot be loaded when a process attempts to activate.

The code to read and write from the config file is shown here. The ConfigurationManager uses static methods which are documented as being thread safe.

```
public static class IsRunningProcesser
{

    public static void SetRunning(bool isRunning)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        config.AppSettings.Settings[Constants.IsRunning].Value =
            isRunning.ToString();
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(Constants.AppSettings);
    }

    public static void ClearRunning()
    {
        SetRunning(false);
    }

    public static bool IsRunning()
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(Constants.AppSettings);

        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.AppSettings.Settings[Constants.IsRunning].Value) && (config.AppSettings.Settings[Constants.IsRunning].Value.ToLower() == "true");

    }
}
```

This is the main touch point however the config file could be accessed in a number of places. It also stores the settings required to communicate with the WCF services these processes are configured to use. It should be noted that the internet connection on some of these machines can be flaky.

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Is this a threading issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about creating a log and logging your changes and then check the log when it occurs?

Comment: Is it possible that the data you are saving in the config file is already garbage?